# Determine the two unit vectors in which the directional derivative of f at (2,4) is equal to $0$. Why is the equation $a^2+b^2=1$ used at the end?

Tags: calculus

I have the equation and the gradient. So, $$▽f(x,y)·\vec u=0$$. With the gradient $〈-16,-24〉$.

$$▽f(2,4)=〈-16,-24〉; u=〈a,b〉$$

$$ 〈-16,-24〉.〈a,b〉=(-16)a+(-24)b=0$$

Solve for **a**

$$(-16)a+(-24)b=0$$

$$a=\frac{-3b}{2}$$

When **a** is plugged into $[a^2+b^2=1]$

$$\frac{-3b^2}{2}+b^2=1$$

$$b=\pm \frac{2\sqrt{13}}{13}$$
We plug **b** in and get the value for **a**.

$$a=\frac{-3}{2}(\frac{2\sqrt 13}{13})=\frac{-3\sqrt 13}{13}$$

Therefore when **b** is positive, $u_1=〈\frac{-3\sqrt13}{13},\frac{2\sqrt13}{13}〉$ and when **b** is negative $u_2=〈\frac{3\sqrt13}{13},\frac{-2\sqrt13}{13}〉$

My question is where does the $[a^2+b^2=1]$ come in? Why is that used?

Answer (score 1):

The title says:

> Determine the two **unit** vectors in which the directional derivative of f at (2,4) is equal to $0$. Why is the equation $a^2+b^2=1$ used at the end?

Using the equation of a unit circle, $a^2+b^2=1$, ensures the resulting vectors of the form $\langle a, b\rangle$ are unit vectors.